# Having a hard time proving this limit

Tags: limits, asymptotics, quadratics

How can I prove this limit?

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-4x+5} = x-2$$

Graphically, it is easy to see that this is true, but is it possible to prove it mathematically?

EDIT:

I'm sorry, it appears that I worded my question wrong? I don't quite understand what I should do to correct it, but I will try to rephrase instead.

I'm trying to mathematically prove that for big values of $x$ the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$ starts to resemble the linear function $g(x)=x-2$. Is this possible?

And as a side note, I would love to thoroughly know what I did wrong the first time, I've read all the comments, but I still don't quite understand. Thank you.

Comment: What does that equality *mean*?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you sure about the wording of the question?

Comment: The limit of your expression as $x\rightarrow +\infty$ should not involve $x$, please verifiy the wording of your question.

Comment: The limit in question doesn't make sense. What makes sense, however, is that $\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}\to x-2$ asymptotically, for which, note that $\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}$ and that for sufficiently large $v$, we have $\sqrt{v^2+1}-v\to 0$. Perhaps a more precise wording is that given $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists $k\gt 0$ such that for all $x\ge k$, we have $|\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}-(x-2)|\lt\epsilon$

Comment: You can show: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}-(x-2)\right)=0$$ But as stated, the limit in your question is meaningless because $x$ is not a “free variable” in the limit expression. It doesn’t refer to one value of $x,$ but about the value for all values of $x.$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Or more simply, $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}-(x-2)=0$$

Comment: @DonThousand: True. I should have written just that. :'|$~~$ Though I think "$\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}\sim x-2$ asymptotically" is more concise and readable. The inequality definition for the limit should be useful to OP, I hope. +1 to your comment though! :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}=x\sqrt{1-4/x+5/x^2}= x-2+O(1/x)$.

Comment: Perhaps take a limit of x-2 as x goes to infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with what you did wrong: This expression
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$$
does not depend on a variable $x$. There is no $x$ in it. The $x$ you see is a dummy variable. That $x$ exists only within that notation, and is there only to make the notation work. In computing, they call that "scope". $x$ comes into existence with the "lim" and goes back out of existence after the $5$ and the closing of the square root.

The expression represents a single value (though in this case, not a member of the real numbers, but $\infty$). It is not a variable expression. It is not a function. It is a single value. On the other hand, "$x - 2$" is a variable expression. It takes on different values for different values of $x$, which is a free variable here. It has no relation to the dummy variable $x$ that appears on the left and does not exist on the right.

So what you wrote reduces to $$\infty = x - 2$$
It is only true if $x = \infty$, which is not a value that normally $x$ is allowed to even take. (That is why we talk about the "limit as $x\to \infty$" and not the "value at $x = \infty$".) So your question as stated didn't make sense.

What should you have written? You actually meant that the two functions $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$ and $g(x)$ are asymptotic as $x \to \infty$. There are different ways to define this. The comments have it interpreted as
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\sqrt{x^2-4x+5} - (x-2)\right] = 0$$

This is somewhat tricky to show. herb steinberg almost has it, but doesn't justify the claim that it is $x - 2 + O(1/x)$. What you should start with is a change of variable: let $t = x - 2$, noting that $t \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and vice versa> Then it becomes
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \sqrt{t^2+1} - t = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{t^2}} - 1}{\frac1t}= \lim_{s \to 0+} \frac{\sqrt{1+s^2} - 1}s = f'(0)$$
where $f(s) = \sqrt{1+s^2}$. It is easily checked that $f'(0) = 0$.

A somewhat looser definition is $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}}{x-2}\right] = 1$$
Which is easy to prove, since for $x > 2$, $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}}{x-2} = \sqrt{ 1 + \frac 1{(x-2)^2}}$$

Comment: You answered my original question, and thank you for that, but I still don't understand why that limit is wrong. I know what scope means, I'm somewhat of a programmer, but that doesn't help. I've read your answer 5 times now, and still don't get it. I'm sorry, but when I put in that function as a graph, the bigger $x$ gets, the more the function resembles $x-2$, so why is my notation wrong? Isn't it implying that as $x$ gets bigger, $\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$ starts to look like $x-2$?

Comment: "the bigger $x$ gets, the more the function resembles $x−2$." That is not what you wrote down. It is what either of the two re-interpretations I (and the commenters) offered means. But what you wrote down means something *different*. $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2-4x+5} = \infty$. That whole limit expression is just a way of writing $\infty$. It doesn't say anything more about the function $\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$ other than that if grows without bound as $x\to \infty$. So you wrote down $\infty = x - 2$, and *that is ALL you wrote down*. There is nothing there about $x$ short of $\infty$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for you to see it, if the dummy variable in the limit were not labeled the same as the external free variable. These are different variables. They cannot be the same, since one is just a dummy variable, and the other is free. The labels on dummy variables can be changed without changing the expression: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2-4x+5} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\sqrt{t^2-4t+5} = \lim_{p\to\infty}\sqrt{p^2-4p+5}$$ It means the same *single* value, no matter which variable is used. So a better way to write your equation is $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\sqrt{t^2-4t+5} = x - 2$$

Comment: Now do you see that the left side is just a single "number", and what you've written is at best true for only one value of $x$ (and in this case, not a value that $x$ is even allowed to take)?

Comment: Ah I see now, yes the switching of the variables definitely helped make it clear. It seems my understanding of limit notation may have not been as through as I would have liked to believe... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Since you say you are a programmer. Let me offer some pseudocode: The limit is a kind of function: `function LimitAtInfty(function f) { real x = 1, real y; while( x < infty) {x = x + 1; y = f(x)}; return y }` (sorry having to one-line it, and of course this is an inaccurate representation of both actual computing and the math of a limit, but you get the idea). Now we define the function to pass:  `function f(real x) = sqr(x^2 - 4x + 5)` and then later you use it as `assert LimitAtInfy(f) = x - 2`, where the compiler will give you an "undefined variable x" error.

Comment: Sorry, you posted your reply while I was putting this final example together, and I didn't see it until you finished. But I'll still leave it in case it is helpful to someone else.

Comment: No need to apologize, it was still very informative! The programming perspective has made it even more intuitive; it's always practical to discuss things in code.